# How to dynamically set the put n*"_" for SAS

Tags: sas

Tech: SAS 9.3

Currently working in SAS with a programming background vs a BI background.
Also running SAS from a scheduler, and not using EG or any SAS product to run my sas programs

This is what I want to see in my log file:

```
==================================================================
========================SAS Program Name==========================
==================================================================
```

Need to do this dynamically so that I can hand off the bit to our contractors to use so we have unified logs, instead of hardcoding it in each of the 500+ sas programs they're creating and modifying.

This is as far as I got

```
data _null_;
   LL=%scan(%sysfunc(getoption(linesize,KEYWORD)),2,"=");
   put 132*'=';
   put "&progName";
   put 132*'=';
run;
```

What I would is something that looks like this:

```
data _null_;
   LL=%scan(%sysfunc(getoption(linesize,KEYWORD)),2,"=");
   padding = (LL - %length("&progName"))/2;
   padding = round(padding,1);
   put LL*'=';
   put padding*'=' "&progName" padding*'=';
   put LL*'=';
run;
```

Is this possible using the put command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
34         %let progname=SAS Program Name.sas;
35         data _null_;
36            LL=input(getoption('linesize'),f8.);
37            put @;
38            _file_ = repeat('=',ll-1);
39            put;
40            progname=translate("&progname",'ff'x,' ');
41            put progname $varying256.-c ll @;
42            _file_ = translate(_file_,'=',' ',' ','ff'x);
43            put ;
44            _file_ = repeat('=',ll-1);
45            put;
46            run;

====================================================================================================================================
========================================================SAS Program Name.sas========================================================
====================================================================================================================================
```

You could make it a stored program...  Update I changed double quoted macro variable reference to SYMGET in the stored version.  Otherwise it would only print the program when it was compiled.

```
%let progname=SAS Program Name.sas;
data _null_ / pgm=work.banner;
   LL=input(getoption('linesize'),f8.);
   progname=translate(symget('progname'),'ff'x,' ');
   put @;
   _file_ = repeat('=',ll-1); put;
   put progname $varying256.-c ll @;
   _file_ = translate(_file_,'=',' ',' ','ff'x);   put ;
   _file_ = repeat('=',ll-1); put;
   run; 

data pgm=work.banner;
   run;
```

Comment: Well, this is 100% the answer to how to make what I need, but half this stuff I don't even understand yet. (having to teach myself SAS on the job)
I'm guessing f8, ff,  are format types?

And I don't even know what $varying256 is yet. Trying to google that now.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now.
'ff'x is the last position in the translate table. '00'x would be the start.
varying256 is a format that allows for a large string. -c center's whatever you're putting in there, and the LL is the variable with the total length. The command will stick what you told it to somewhere in the middle of the length padding it with spaces.

Then you translate the most recently put line and replace all space characters with equal symbols from start to end 'ff'x.

Nice.

Comment: Very close. Except the 'FF'X is just a place holder ASCII code to use so that the original spaces in the value of the macro variable `PROGRAM` do not get translated to '=' also. So first the spaces are replaced with 'FF'X and then in the last step the spaces are replaced with '=' and the 'FF'X characters are converted back into spaces.

Comment: Now I'm having to try and figure out how to make this into a MACRO thing so that we can put it into a library file (to be included in all programs) and called like so:

%headerandfooter(&progName);

But when I try to modify what you wrote, it's not working at all. lol. Guess I have to keep trying...

Comment: It should be macrofiable.  Maybe starting a new question would be a good way to get help with the macro part.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with simple math. If you ever took a typing class using a real typewriter then you may remember how to center titles on the paper.

In this case, I determine how many equals I need to pad the program name by subtracting the length of the program name from the line length. Then divide that number in half to determine how many before and after the program name. The `cats` function concatenates the equals string before and after the program name. Simple as that.

```
options linesize=65;

%let progname = My SAS Program;

data _null_;
ll = input(getoption('linesize'), 5.);
put @;
_file_ = repeat('=', ll-1);
put;
equals = repeat('=', (ll-length(strip("&progname"))-1)/2);
_file_ = cats(equals, "&progname", equals);
put;
_file_ = repeat('=', ll-1);
put;
run;
```

The output in the log:

```
 =================================================================
 ==========================My SAS Program=========================
 =================================================================
```